# making nav li reach end of page

Tags: html, css, nav

I am trying to figure out how to remove the last black section of my secondary nav.
I want the "wishlist" link to be the last thing there, not have the border and then more black space afterwards basically. I'm just not sure how to do this.

my html:

```
<title>LOST Collector</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>        
</head>
    <body>
        <!--Header-->
        <header>    
            <a href="http://www.lostcollector.com">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Lost Collector" title="Lost Collector"/>
            </a>
            <!--Primary navigation-->
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="template.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="template.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="template.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
         <!-- Secondary Navigation -->
        <ul id="navigation_layout">
          <li><a href="artwork.html">Artwork</a></li>
          <li><a href="autographs.html">Autographs</a></li>
          <li><a href="booksandmagazines.html">Books/Magazines</a></li>
          <li><a href="clothing.html">Clothing</a></li>
          <li><a href="dvdsandcds.html">Dvds and Cds</a></li>
          <li><a href="filmcrew.html">Film Crew</a></li>
          <li><a href="originalprops.html">Original Props</a></li>
          <li><a href="specialevents.html">Special Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="toysandgames.html">Toys and games</a></li>
          <li><a href="tradingcards.html">Trading cards</a></li>
          <li><a href="everythingelse.html">Everything else</a></li>
          <li><a href="wishlist.html">Wish list</a></li>
        </ul>
```

my css:

```
   body {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 130px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #111111;
    font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 90%;
}

header a {
    float:left; 
    display:inline-block;
}

     header a img {
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right:10px;
     display: inline;
     height: 112px;
     width:; 113px;
}

 nav {
     display: inline;
     float: right;
}

nav ul  {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding: 40px 30px;
    padding: right 10px;
}   

nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
} 

nav li a:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*secondary navigation*/
 #navigation_layout {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none; 
    background-color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#navigation_layout li {
    float: left;
}
#navigation_layout li a  {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
#navigation_layout li a:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
    background-color: #fff; 
}
```

I have put it into a jsfiddle here, so it is clearer what I am trying to do. 
https://jsfiddle.net/thzfm0fe/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the background color to your list items `<li>` and not the `<ul>`.

Remove `background-color` from here:

```
#navigation_layout {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    /* background-color: #000000; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

And add to here:

```
#navigation_layout li {
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thzfm0fe/3/

A `<ul>` by default is a block level element and will fill up the full width of the parent element. Your list items `<li>` did not fill up the full width of the parent but your `<ul>` did, hence the extra black after your list items.

By applying the background color to the `<li>` you don't need to add white border to your anchors anymore. You could apply a margin instead.